# Jenkins Build is not stopped after successfully passing the Integration test

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

Hi I am new to Jenkins.

I have configure the Jenkins locally on my machine and Its running fine.

I need to ask whenever my Integration tests (written in Junit) are passed, Jenkin doesn't stops the build and its continue.

But in logs It displays the test cases are passed and no errors are found.

Could some one please suggest any solution how to stop jenkins build?

My Code:

```
package com.workshop.airport.workshop.airport;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class PageStepsDefs {

    public String ChromeDriverPath="C:\\Users\\zain.jamshaid\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe";
    public WebDriver webdriver;
    String localhost="http://www.google.com";



    public PageStepsDefs (){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",ChromeDriverPath);
        webdriver = new ChromeDriver(); 
    }

    @Given("^I browse to the (.+) page$")
    public void open_page(String url)
    {
        webdriver.get(localhost+url);
        System.out.println(localhost+url);
    }

    @When("^I click on the button (.+)$")
    public void click_On_Menu(String Id)
    {
        webdriver.findElement(By.id(Id)).click();
        System.out.print(Id);
    }

    @After
    public void close_browser(){
        webdriver.close();
    }
}
```

I have also attached the screenshot of jenkins console logs

[image: Jenkins Console Log ScreenShot]

Any help will be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you stop all child processes started in the script?  Hudson is probably waiting for child processes to exit

Comment: Hi Jayan,

I believe I have stopped all the process, You can have a look into my code. I have added it. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I was using webDriver.close();
but
webDriver.quit();
fix my problem

This fixed the problem